# Underscore sortBy algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I need your help for a little algorithme for my app :

i have an object like this :

```
var obj = { "response" : [
    "candidate" : {
        "id":"1",
        "price" : 10,
        "distance" : 20
    },
    "candidate" : {
        "id":"2"
        "price" : 14,
        "distance" : 2
    },
    "candidate" : {
        "id":"3",
        "price" : 200,
        "distance" : 1
    }
] }
```

Which i sort by price like this :

```
var sortPrice = _(obj.response).sortBy(function(p){
    return p.candidate.price
})
```

It works fine and sort the object (ids) : 1,2,3

Now if candidate has the same price but different distance, i should show first candidate with the same price and the lowest distance :

```
var obj = { "response" : [
    "candidate" : {
        "id":"1",
        "price" : 10,
        "distance" : 20
    },
    "candidate" : {
        "id":"2"
        "price" : 10,
        "distance" : 2
    },
    "candidate" : {
        "id":"3",
        "price" : 200,
        "distance" : 1
    }
] }

var sorted = _(obj.response).chain().sortBy(function (p) { 
    return parseInt(p.candidate.price) ; 
}).sortBy(function(d){
    return parseInt(d.candidate.distance)
}).value();
```

But it sort me the lowest distance first (ids) : 3(with distance 1), 2(with distance 2), 1(with distance 20) than 2,1,3

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.3#sortBy) is a fork of underscore that allows you to sort by several properties of the object.

Using it, a solution could be:

```
_(obj.response).map(_.partial(_.get, _, 'candidate')).sortBy(['price', 'distance']).value();
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwbm3xtg/) in case you want to play with it.

Comment: Thank you for response, i don't use lodash for now, but your code is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In pure js you can use `sort()` like this.

```js
var obj = {
  "response": [{
    "candidate": {
      "id": "1",
      "price": 8,
      "distance": 20
    }
  }, {
    "candidate": {
      "id": "2",
      "price": 8,
      "distance": 2
    }
  }, {
    "candidate": {
      "id": "3",
      "price": 200,
      "distance": 1
    }
  }]
}

obj.response.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.candidate.price - b.candidate.price || a.candidate.distance - b.candidate.distance;
})

console.log(obj.response)
```

Comment: Yes, I agree - plain `sort` seems good enough. I'm not sure it's doable in Underscore.

Comment: Works perfectly, about you is it possible to add third argument ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: I mean adding another attribute to the object and sort also with it, let's say a new attribute "aptitude" with value "php or mysql" and sort by candidate with minimum price, lowest distance and php skills